# Error comes as "Uncaught TypeError: notesObj.push is not a function at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous>" . Please anyone suggest what to do

Tags: javascript, arrays, typeerror

```
let addBtn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
  let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
  if (notes == null) {
    notesObj = [];
  }
  else {
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
  }
  notesObj.push(addTxt.value);
  localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
  addTxt.value = "";
```

});

Not only "push" it doesn't take any other Array function as well.
P.S: I have used bootstrap for styling.

Comment: What is the value of `notes` or `notesObj`? You can identify the issue by adding some`console.log` and `debugger;`

Comment: "notesObj.push is not a function" simply translates to "notesObj is not an array"; this should help solve this. Note that you should probably do `let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes") || "[]";`; that way it will work if localStorage was cleared.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> notesObj.push is not a function

means that **notesObj** has no function with the name **push**, in this scenario, it's because **notesObj** is not an array. Let's trace the code back to see why **notesObj** is not an array.

```
let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
notesObj = JSON.parse(notes)
```

Based on these two lines of code, notesObj is the return value of a localStorage item after being parsed as a JSON. based on [the official documentation of the localStorage.getItem()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), the return value of this expression will be **null** if the item was not set (which will be the case the first time the code is executed) which can cause such an error.

**Solution**: You can solve this issue either by setting the initial value of the specified item in the localStorage or preferably by validating its type before using it.

**Example**:

```
let btn = document.getElementById("addBtn");
addBtn.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    let addTxt = document.getElementById("addTxt");
    let notes = localStorage.getItem("notes");
    notesObj = JSON.parse(notes);
    if(notesObj === null) notesObj= []; // This sets it to an empty array initially
    notesObj.push(addTxt.value);
    localStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(notesObj));
    addTxt.value = "";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but a little bit error in your code which I have fixed. Instead of notes = [ ] it should be notesObj = [ ]. BTW thabks man.

Comment: Yes. sorry I didn't sleep well XD